# build Fortran .lib x64 bit on windows 10 using VS2015 and link it to C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, fortran, 64-bit

I'm building a c++ and Fortran mixed program using VS2015, which was perfectly fine on windows 7. A Fortran XXX.lib was first built and then linked to C++ XXX_main (build dependencies -> project dependencies). Now I'm trying to migrate it to windows 10 with target computer x64, but still using VS2015 and there are compiling errors that I cannot find solutions after weeks searching.

Here is the compiling information:

```
------ Neues Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: XXX, Konfiguration: Debug x64 ------
1>Deleting intermediate files and output files for project 'XXX', configuration 'Debug|x64'.
1>Compiling with Intel(R) Visual Fortran Compiler 19.0.5.281 [Intel(R) 64]...
1>scout2d.f
1>E:\test\src\scout2d.f(74): error #8110: The module file for compiler-generated interface was generated for a different platform or by an incompatible compiler or compiler release. It cannot be read. Use -gen-interfaces option.   [XGET__GENMOD]
1>fortcom: Fatal: There has been an internal compiler error (C0000005).
1>compilation aborted for E:\test\src\scout2d.f (code 1)
...........
1>scp_lib - 82 error(s), 18 warning(s)
1>XXX - 82 error(s), 18 warning(s)
2>------ Neues Erstellen gestartet: Projekt: XXX_main, Konfiguration: Debug x64 ------
...........
2>  XXX_main.vcxproj -> E:\test\x64\Debug\XXX_main.exe
2>  XXX_main.vcxproj -> E:\test\x64\Debug\/XXX_main.pdb (Full PDB)
========== Alles neu erstellen: 1 erfolgreich, 1 fehlerhaft, 0 übersprungen ==========
```

The sources files are of course the same as on windows 7. Here are the changes that I've made or tried on windows 10 using VS2015 regarding to x64 system. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

1. XXX_main project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> additional dependencies and libraries: same as before
2. XXX_main project Properties -> C++ -> include folders: same as before
3. XXX_main project Properties -> Linker -> advanced -> Target computer: change MachineX84 to MachineX64
4. Configurations Manager -> Platform: x64
5. Option -> Intel Compilers and tools -> C++ -> Compilers: change win32 to x64
6. Option -> Intel Compilers and tools ->Visual Fortran -> Compilers 
   -> Includes: add $(IFORT_COMPILER15)\compiler\include 
   -> Libraries: add $(IFORT_COMPILER15)\compiler\lib\intel64
7. Deinstallation and new installation of Fortran compilers, the current version is:
   Intel(R) Visual Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, version 19.0.5
8. Deinstallation and new installation of Visual Studio 2015, the current version is 14.0.25431.01
   Update 3
9. Fortran XXX project Properties -> Libraries -> out: x64\Debug\XXX.lib

Comment: The error message says what to do: "The module file for compiler-generated interface was generated for a different platform or by an incompatible compiler or compiler release. It cannot be read. Use -gen-interfaces option": have you done this?

Comment: Hi Richard, the platform is x64, and the compiler is also for x64. Can you please explain more what else I should check? I'm afraid that I may not clearly understood this message.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions on regenerating the module file as stated in the text of the error message in your question (which I quoted in my previous comment)?

Comment: If you mean the *.mod files unter \x64\Debug\ or \x64\Release\, they are all new. I've deleted all the old *.mod files including the scout2d.mod.         Or do you mean something else by regenerating the module files?

Comment: Please read the error message the compiler gave you: that says you need to rebuild the module files with the new configuration, and what command line option to use to do so.

Comment: Yes, I have read it. But the way to rebuild the module files is not clear to me. I did it by deleting the *.mod files under /x64/Debug/. Can you clarify how would you rebuild the module files specifically?

Comment: I've never used Fortran in Visual Studio. Therefore I understand the words in the error message, but may not exactly know what to deal with it.

Comment: You're going to need to read the documentation on how to rebuild the module files (the error tells you switch command line switch to use). I would look to run this from a command line where I can see exactly which commands are being used (VS makes life easy by hiding lots of details, but sometimes those details are important).

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Here is what I did:

1. Deinstall Intel Fortran Compiler (restart PC) and install it again  (restart PC)
2. Right click on Fortran project XXX -> Properties -> Fortran -> External Procedures
   -> Calling Convention: change it to CVF (/iface:cvf).
3. Right click on C++ project XXX_main -> Properties -> VC++ Folders -> Library folders: add the Fortran compiler path $(IFORT_COMPILER19)\compiler\lib\intel64

Thanks for the help anyhow.
Best Regards